# Fetch a row inserted to SQL server in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm writing in part of my code in PHP that insert a row in my SQL server like below code :

```
$stmtInsertAdmin = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "INSERT INTO $dbtable_participant   ( A ,B, C,D ,E , F, G, H)
    VALUES ( '$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f', 1 , 0 ) ");
```

Then I want to get this new row that inserted in my SQL server and pass it to my rest of codes. (I don't want to do another query for selecting this row and then fetch it). Anybody has a new idea?

Comment: Before this, fix your injection issue. It looks like you're injecting both the table's name *and* the values; this is a security risk just waiting to be exploited. Why do you need to inject the table's name at all here? That smells of a design flaw on it's own.

Comment: You already have $a , $b, $c, $d, $e and $f  (otherwise you cannot do the insert operation, right ?) . So what is the problem you encounter in the subsequent coding using these data ?

Comment: _“and pass it to my rest of codes”_ - pass it _as what_, exactly? You won’t get what `sqlsrv_query` for a SELECT query would return – a statement resource – magically out of nowhere, but if you just need to pass along what sqlsrv_fetch_array/_object would return … well then create that array or object yourself, you _have_ all the values.

Comment: Does this table have an auto_increment ID field as the primary key? Are you perhaps asking how to get the automatically generated value of that ID after the row was inserted? I can't think of any other reason why you'd need to fetch the row after it was inserted, because - as others have already pointed out - your code already has access to the rest of the data: it's stored in the variables you used to insert the row.